# How to align a top-align a table that starts with an \hline?

Tags: tables

I want to TeXify this [document](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN252457811_1894&DMDID=dmdlog34) as an exercise. At the bottom of its second page, there are some tables. I tried to create something similar to this using LaTeX and finally did this:

```
Von den 15 Zerlegungen \emph{bei} $\mu=4$ sind die ersten sieben:
\begin{flushleft}
$v=2;\ p=
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}\hline
$-1$&$-256$\\\hline
\end{tabular}$
[bedeutet: $(-1)^2+(-256)^2=p$]\\
$v=3;\ p=
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}\hline
$255$&$0$\\\hline
$-16$&$-16$\\\hline
\end{tabular}$
\end{flushleft}
```

To me, that code seems very strange and it doesn't works. Can some TeXpert help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage{array}
...

Von den 15 Zerlegungen \emph{bei} $\mu=4$ sind die ersten sieben:
\begin{flushleft}
$v=2$; $p=
\begin{array}[t]{|c|c|}
\firsthline
-1&-256\\
\lasthline
\end{array}$
[bedeutet: $(-1)^2+(-256)^2=p$]\\
$v=3$; $p=
\begin{array}[t]{|c|c|}
\firsthline
255&0\\
\hline
-16&-16\\
\lasthline
\end{array}$
\end{flushleft}
```

In these particular examples `\lasthline` is not really necessary; but it's handy to put it there, so if we change our mind and want bottom alignment all we need is to change the optional argument to `array`. These commands work, of course, also for `tabular`. They won't do any good if the first table row has excessive height.

Some advices. Use `array` in math mode, it spares you from putting so many `$` symbols. Notice also the `$` before the semicolon: different formulas should be segregated on their own.

Comment: Good advice! Btw. there's further `\lasthline`, useful if bottom alignment is desired.

Comment: @Stefan: I'll add `\lasthline`, thanks.

Comment: @egreg Another little question: How can I get the columns to have all the same size?

Comment: For that you need the `p` specifier and fix the width yourself. Or use `\makebox[\widthof{$-256$}]{$-1$}` (requires the **calc** package).

Comment: @egreg When I use the `p` specifier, the contents of the array aren't typeset in math mode anymore. That's weird.

Comment: That's normal. But you can say `>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{1cm}<{$}` and get fixed width columns with centered math mode entry.